# ASP.NET MVC 3, MVCScaffolding Nuget : Re-creating tables

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm currently developing a CMS for a website I'm making. I'm using MVCScaffolding to quickly make my controllers. Everything worked very well but...

I have a question. I created a new database so now I don’t have any of my tables in it yet. Is there any way of recreating my tables with a simple command? I tried hard to find a way but found nothing yet.

Anyone has an idea? I still have all my models, etc. I just want to recreate the tables so I could continue to use them.

Thanks a lot!

If you don't MVCScaffolding yet go take a look it is awesome!
http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/01/13/scaffold-your-aspnet-mvc-3-project-with-the-mvcscaffolding-package/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is pretty simple : You have to run the app and access the module. It'll trigger the creation process.